# Get back commits from modified pull requests

Tags: git, pull-request

I had someone send me a pull request on a project my team is working. However, I need to make a lot of changes before I could merge it into working branch. I wasn't sure how to do this, so I searched for it and came across [this](https://dev.to/bolajiayodeji/how-to-test-a-pull-request-locally-before-merging-1h29). It shows how to fetch the pull request and make changes, evaluate it and then merge into master. I did this and was put in branch `e95c037`.

I made a lot of changes and was satisfied and ready to merge it in. When I checked out master, I got a warning saying that you are leaving back a bunch of commits. Then when I followed last two steps

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Modified PR"
```

nothing happened. I don't have access to my new changes. I tried checking out `e95c073` is said this:

```
Note: checking out 'e95c037'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at e95c037... Change name
```

but my files are not there. The new directory structure (that I created while modifying the pull request is there) but there are no files inside these directories.

Have I lost everything? If I can get everything back, how do I merge this modified pull request correclty?

Comment: Run `git reflog`, you can find at which commit you had been before you checked out `master`. That commit contains all your new changes. You can simply check it out or create a branch from it. A branch would be better.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to retrieve my changes and properly merge it. What is the best practice to evaluate a pull request and possibly modify it before merging it?

Comment: For `git checkout FETCH_HEAD` in the tutorial, it's better to use `git checkout -b foo FETCH_HEAD` instead, so that a local branch `foo` is created. A branch is more user friendly than a detached HEAD.